# Identifier not found - error C3861 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visibility, function-declaration

I have a problem with my code. Unfortunately, when compiling I get these errors all the time. What can this be caused by and how to fix it?

> error C3861: 'print': identifier not found

My code:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "pojazdy.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Pojazdy** poj;
    int size{ 0 }, index{ 0 };
    Petla(poj, size);

    print(poj, size);

    wyrejestruj(poj,size,0);
    print(poj, size);
    wyrejestruj(poj,size);

    return 0;
}
```

**pojazdy.h**

```cpp
#ifndef pojazdy_h
#define pojazdy_h

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Pojazdy
{
public:
    string typ;
    string marka;
    string model;
    string z_dod;
    int ilosc;
    int cena;

    void dodaj();
    void d_pojazd(Pojazdy**& pojazdy, int& size);
    void wyrejestruj(Pojazdy**& pojazdy, int& size, int index);
    void print(Pojazdy** pojazdy, int size);
    void Petla(Pojazdy**& p, int& size);

    //void wyswietl();
    int get_ilosc() { return ilosc; }
    string get_typ() { return typ; }
    string get_marka() { return marka; }
    string get_model() { return model; }
    int get_cena() { return cena; }
    void set_ilosc(int x);
};

#endif
```

**pojazdy.cpp**

```cpp
#include "pojazdy.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Pojazdy::set_ilosc(int x) { ilosc = x; }

void Pojazdy::dodaj()
{
    cout << "DODAWANIE POJAZDU..." << endl;
    cout << "Podaj typ pojazdu:";
    cin >> typ;

    cout << "Podaj marke pojazdu: ";
    cin >> marka;

    cout << "Podaj model pojazdu: ";
    cin >> model;

    cout << "Dodaj cene pojazdu: ";
    cin >> cena;
}

void Petla(Pojazdy**& p, int& size) {
    char z_dod;// = 'N';
    do {
        d_pojazd(p, size); //odpowiada za dodawnie
        p[size - 1]->dodaj();
        cout << "Czy chcesz zakonczyc dodawanie? Jesli tak, wcisnij Y/N: ";
        cin >> z_dod;

    } while (z_dod == 'N' || z_dod == 'n');//while (p[size]->z_dod == "N" ||p[size]->z_dod == "n");
}

void print(Pojazdy** pojazdy, int size) {
    std::cout << "====================================" << std::endl;
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << "Typ: " << pojazdy[i]->get_typ() << " Marka: " << pojazdy[i]->get_marka() << " Model: " << pojazdy[i]->get_model() << " Cena: " << pojazdy[i]->get_model() << std::endl;
}

void wyrejestruj(Pojazdy**& pojazdy, int& size) {
    for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < size; i++)
        delete pojazdy[i];
    delete[] pojazdy;
    size = 0;
    pojazdy = NULL;
}

void wyrejestruj(Pojazdy**& pojazdy, int& size, int index) {
    if (index < size) {
        Pojazdy** temp = new Pojazdy * [size - 1];
        short int j{ -1 };
        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < size; i++) {
            if (i != index) {
                j++;
                temp[j] = pojazdy[i];
            }
        }
        delete[] pojazdy;
        --size;
        pojazdy = temp;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Pamiec zwolniona!" << std::endl;
}

void d_pojazd(Pojazdy**& pojazdy, int& size) {
    Pojazdy** temp = new Pojazdy * [size + 1];
    if (size == 0)
        temp[size] = new Pojazdy;
    else {
        for (int i{ 0 }; i < size; i++)
            temp[i] = pojazdy[i];
        delete[] pojazdy;

        temp[size] = new Pojazdy;
    }
    ++size;
    pojazdy = temp;
}
```

I used `#ifndef`, `#define`, `#endif` and `#pragma once`, but none of them work. I will be really grateful for every code, I am already tired of this second hour. And forgive the non-English variables and function names for them - it's university code, so I didn't feel the need.

Comment: Where do you declare/define the `print` function?  C++ doesn't have a built in print function.

Comment: `Pozady` has function `print`; To invoke that method, if that is your intention, you need to create an object of it and call it

Comment: @NathanOliver 
Print is just a name. I call it in my main.cpp and its operation is found in vehicles.cpp

Comment: @Wander3r
Could you create the sample code and show me what it would look like?

Comment: You have quite a few namespacing mistakes in your implementation. `main.cpp` attempts to use a function `print(Pojazdy**, int)`, but not such function is declared. `pojazdy.h` declares the function `Pojazdy::print(Pojzady**&, int&)`, but this function is never defined. `pojazdy.cpp` then defines the function `print(Pojazdy**&, int&)`, but this function is unusable since you never declare it directly or via a header in any other file. Your use of references to pointers is also very questionable. You may want to step back and re-read your textbook on classes and pointers before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

Move the functions below outside the class declaration.

```
void wyrejestruj(Pojazdy**& pojazdy, int& size, int index);
void print(Pojazdy** pojazdy, int size);
void Petla(Pojazdy**& p, int& size);
```

Or make them static and call like `Pojazdy::print(poj, size);`.

Comment: I did so, but I got more errors: error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'Pojazdy::typ'`

Answer (score 1):

You declared a non-static member function print in the class definition

```
class Pojazdy
{
public:
    // ...
    void print(Pojazdy** pojazdy, int size);
    //...
```

but you are trying to call it as a stand-alone function in main

```
print(poj, size);
```

So the compiler issues an error.

The declaration of the function as a stand alone function that at the same time is its definition in the file `pojazdy.cpp` is not visible in the module with main because this module includes only the header with the class declaration.

You should decide whether this function should be a member function of the class or a stand alone function.

Comment: From previous question, it should be a standalone function. I told the OP to add function prototypes, unfortunately he put thiem into the class declaration instead of afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your member functions correctly. `print` can only be called on an object of type `Pojazdy`, so you need to do something like:

```
Pojazdy** poj;
int size{ 0 }, index{ 0 };

Pojazdy x;   // Creates an object of Pojazdy called z

x.print(poj,size); // Calls the print method on x
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to have to declare an object, you could make the method `static` and just call it on the class.

In the .h file:

```
static void print(Pojazdy** pojazdy, int size);
```

And then in main:

```
Pojazdy** poj;
int size{ 0 }, index{ 0 };

Pojazdy::print(poj, size); // Calls the print method on the class
```

Comment: They also need to fix the CPP file as the function is not defined as a member function in the CPP file.

Comment: I did so, but I got more errors: error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'Pojazdy::typ'` –

Comment: The functions are not meant to be members of the class, it's the prototypes that are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You put your function prototypes in the wrong place. They should be after the class decalration.

```
class Pojazdy
{
    ...
};

void print(Pojazdy** pojazdy, int size);
void wyrejestruj(Pojazdy**& pojazdy, int& size);
```

etc.

`print` is not a member of the `Pojazdy` class, so it's wrong to put the prototype inside the `Pojazdy` class declaration.